# How to handle System.MissingMethodException in Lucent.net dll?

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, lucene.net

I new to Lucene & C#. I am trying to replicate the example given on Lucene.net [tutorial](https://lucenenet.apache.org/quick-start/tutorial.html) but when i running the code it is showing

```
Unhandled exception. System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(System.IO.FileStream, System.String, Int64, System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFileAccess, System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFileSecurity, System.IO.HandleInheritability, Boolean)'.
   at Lucene.Net.Store.MMapDirectory.Map(MMapIndexInput input, FileStream fc, Int64 offset, Int64 length)
   at Lucene.Net.Store.MMapDirectory.MMapIndexInput..ctor(MMapDirectory outerInstance, String resourceDescription, FileStream fc)
   at Lucene.Net.Store.MMapDirectory.OpenInput(String name, IOContext context)
   at Lucene.Net.Store.Directory.Copy(Directory to, String src, String dest, IOContext context)
   at Lucene.Net.Store.TrackingDirectoryWrapper.Copy(Directory to, String src, String dest, IOContext context)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.CreateCompoundFile(InfoStream infoStream, Directory directory, CheckAbort checkAbort, SegmentInfo info, IOContext context)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.SealFlushedSegment(FlushedSegment flushedSegment)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.Flush()
   at Lucene.Net.Index.DocumentsWriter.DoFlush(DocumentsWriterPerThread flushingDWPT)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.DocumentsWriter.FlushAllThreads(IndexWriter indexWriter)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.DoFlush(Boolean applyAllDeletes)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.Flush(Boolean triggerMerge, Boolean applyAllDeletes)
```

I don't know to handle this error or what is error. this error occurring writing the folder , sometimes reading the folder it's just so random .

my code

```
const LuceneVersion luceneVersion = LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48; 

//Open the Directory using a Lucene Directory class
string indexName = "example_index";
string indexPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, indexName);


FSDirectory indexDir = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(indexPath));

//Create an analyzer to process the text 
Analyzer standardAnalyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(luceneVersion);

//Create an index writer
IndexWriterConfig indexConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(luceneVersion, standardAnalyzer);
//indexConfig.OpenMode = OpenMode.CREATE;                             // create/overwrite index
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(indexDir, indexConfig);

//Add three documents to the index
Document doc = new Document();
doc.Add(new TextField("titleTag", "The Apache Software Foundation - The world's largest open source foundation.", Field.Store.YES));
doc.Add(new StringField("domain", "www.apache.org/", Field.Store.YES));
writer.AddDocument(doc);

doc = new Document();
doc.Add(new TextField("title", "Powerful open source search library for .NET", Field.Store.YES));
doc.Add(new StringField("domain", "lucenenet.apache.org", Field.Store.YES));
writer.AddDocument(doc);

doc = new Document();
doc.Add(new TextField("title", "Unique gifts made by small businesses in North Carolina.", Field.Store.YES));
doc.Add(new StringField("domain", "www.giftoasis.com", Field.Store.YES));
writer.AddDocument(doc);

// //Flush and commit the index data to the directory
writer.Flush(true,true) ;
writer.Commit();
writer.Dispose() ;

using DirectoryReader reader = writer.GetReader(applyAllDeletes: true);
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

Query query = new TermQuery(new Term("domain", "lucenenet.apache.org"));
TopDocs topDocs = searcher.Search(query,1);         //indicate we want the first 2 results


int numMatchingDocs = topDocs.TotalHits;
Document resultDoc = searcher.Doc(topDocs.ScoreDocs[0].Doc);  //read back first doc from results (ie 0 offset)
string title = resultDoc.Get("title");

Console.WriteLine($"Matching results: {topDocs.TotalHits}");
Console.WriteLine($"Title of first result: {title}");
```

as comments suggest i am adding `.csproj`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp6.0.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v6.0.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Lucene.Net" Version="4.8.0.770-beta" />
    <PackageReference Include="Lucene.Net.Analysis.Common" Version="4.8.0.770-beta" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="6.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Lucene, but this error usually means you have wrong version dependencies. For example, if package `A` was compiled with dependency package `B` v1.2 but in runtime `B` v1.1 was loaded instead of v1.2 you may get this error.

Comment: @Artur         thanks , can you  suggest how to validate all dependencies

Comment: Can you post the content of the `.csproj` file?

Comment: You left off the most important info. What version does the project target, and if targeting dotnet standard, what version does the consuming project target? Dotnet standard and core have a different method sugnature for CreateFromFile than framework.

Comment: @Artur  i have added .csproj file

Comment: @gaurav there is no such thing `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp6.0.0</TargetFramework>`, change it to `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>`. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks). Also, remove the `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v6.0.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>` as it's an old way to specify the target framework version in .NET Framework non-sdk-style projects. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-target-framework-and-target-platform?view=vs-2022).

Comment: Looking into your profile, the whole .NET world seems to be new for you. In short there were three epochs: (1)`.NET Framework` - windows only, now in the sustaining mode. The last version is 4.8. Receives only security patches. (2)`.NET Core` - cross-platform and open source. The last version is 3.1. (3)`.NET` - that is the same as .NET Core but without the Core suffix. It started from version 5.0. You can see that .NET Core missing v4.0. It's because Microsoft wanted to get rid of the `Core` suffix but avoid the confusion between `.NET Framework 4` and `.NET 4` which is actually `.NET Core 4`

Comment: @Artur          i have tried that but still showing that error

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild the solution. In VS open the  `Debug > Windows > Modules` window and check the version of the `System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

The problem is that you are using a really old pre-release version of Lucene.NET prior to when .NET Core support was added which uses a confusing version numbering scheme, `4.8.0.770-beta` and was released only on [MyGet.org](https://www.myget.org/feed/Packages/lucene-net). This version will not support .NET 6.0, it only supports .NET Framework.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Lucene.Net" Version="4.8.0.770-beta" />
  <PackageReference Include="Lucene.Net.Analysis.Common" Version="4.8.0.770-beta" />
</ItemGroup>
```

### Solution

To fix this, use one of the beta versions on [NuGet.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net) instead.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Lucene.Net" Version="4.8.0-beta00016" />
  <PackageReference Include="Lucene.Net.Analysis.Common" Version="4.8.0-beta00016" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Also, be sure to change the target framework moniker to `net6.0` instead of `net6.0.0`. `TargetFrameworkVersion` is unnecessary for .NET 6.0.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp6.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error seems like dependency version problem of your dll's.

1. To check dependencies of your project, first check package versions in csproj file of project.
2. Then check package's(dll's) version by checking properties of dll files wherever you are deploying your project.
3. If both files versions are different you got your problem.
4. You need to copy all dll's which are present in csproj file.
5. You'll get all your dll's inside bin/release folder wherever you are creating build.